# More efficient way of testing 3 boolean variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm testing 3 different boolean variables (user determines true/false). My function creates a different sequence of letters and adds capital letters/numbers/special chars based off these boolean values. I feel like there has to be an efficient/clever way of accomplishing this instead of the following method :

```
if capital_letters and digits and special_char:

    # creates string with random capital letters, digits, and special chars

elif capital_letters and digits and not special_char:

    # creates string with capital letters, digits, but no special chars

elif capital_letters and not digits and not special_char:

    # creates string with capital letters but no digits nor special chars

elif not capital_letters and digits and special_char:
    
    # contains digits and special char but no capital letters

....
```

will keep going until it satisfies all combinations (which would be `3*3*3 = 27` different statements correct?)

Comment: Make your charset a list/array then individually check the 3 booleans, and if it's true, add the associated charset to your total charset.

Comment: It's not `3*3*3 = 27` but `2*2*2 = 8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check each condition once and aggregate possible characters according to it, and in the end randomize that:

```py
import string

chars = ""
if capital_letters:
    chars += string.ascii_uppercase
if digits:
    chars += string.digits
if special_char:
    chars += string.punctuation

create_string(chars)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can conver 3 boolean variables to one int(use just his first 3 bits) and than you can write your `if...elif....elif` in more elegnt way.
try to use this code

```
result = int(capital_letters)
result = (result << 1) + int(digits)
result = (result << 1) + int(special_char)
```

if the result is 0 is mean that 3 of tham are false,

1 in binery is '001' so it represent that `special_char` is the only true

.....

5 is binary is '101' so it mean that `capital_letters` and `special_char` are true

etc...

Comment: If you're decided to use bit flags do not use math operators

Comment: @OlvinRoght I can do it more elegant like this 'reduce((lambda x, y: (x << 1) + y), [capital_letters, digits, special_char])' but how can I do  it without math operators at all?

Comment: Elegant way to do this is [`IntFlag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intflag). And again, you're using math add even in your last comment, which is not good, use logical add instead.

Comment: Check [this](https://repl.it/@testerreplit/WorriedLankyAttributes).

Answer (score 1):

```
conditions = {
'capital_letters':capital_letters,
'digits':digits,
'special_char':special_char
}

for key in conditions:
    if conditions[key] == True:
        print (key)
```

In your dict you store your labels as keys, and boleans relative to your string as values.

Then, you loop over the dict keys, check the bolean and print the label (key) if True.